# Heroku app and "already exists" errors when inserting data

Tags: heroku, sequence, reset

I have a Heroku app that I imported existing data into.  Apparently it has screwed up my pk sequences in all my tables.  How can I reset all the sequences of my tables?

I found this [Rails auto-assigning id that already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068800/rails-auto-assigning-id-that-already-exists)

And it says to use this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |t|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(t)
end;nil
```

My problem is I have no idea how to run this on my Heroku app.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You run whatever you need from Rails console on Heroku by doing this:

```
heroku run bundle exec rails console
```

In fact, you can run a number of commands, but starting them with `heroku run`.