# Devise primary key error on postgresql, heroku, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, devise

It is really odd, I'm trying to create a new user by command line and I'm getting this error:

```
User.create :email => "pheewq+1@gmail.com", :password => '123456789', :password_confirmation => '123456789'

PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(37) already exists.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try This

```
$ heroku run rails console
irb(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each { |t| ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(t) }
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15108735/3034747

Comment: how do I do the same but with laravel php ?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco If you have access to the database directly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync