# Rails reset ALL Postgres sequences?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The following works in the Rails 3 console to reset Postgres sequences:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('menucontrols')
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('statuscodes')
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('wostatuses')
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('taskstatuses')
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('priorities')
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('actcodes')
```

Is there a command that would reset ALL of them instead of having to do each one individually?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is easier

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |t|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(t)
end
```

Answer (score 15):

I found one way to do it from this posting:
[Reset PostgreSQL](http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/01/reset-postgresql-auto-increment-value-in-rails/)

I placed the following into `seed.rb` and ran `rake db:seed`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT id FROM #{table} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") rescue ( puts "Warning: not procesing table #{table}. Id is missing?" ; next )
  ai_val = result.any? ? result.first['id'].to_i + 1 : 1
  puts "Resetting auto increment ID for #{table} to #{ai_val}"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER SEQUENCE #{table}_id_seq RESTART WITH #{ai_val}")
end
```

Comment: Tried doing the `reset_pk_sequence!` approach but ran into issues with it when I used Heroku Postgres VS my dev PG (with tables where it should have worked). Perhaps a result of a newer version of PG vs older version. Anyway, this approach did the job and even any errors. Very nice.

Comment: This is today's "You save my life!". Our DBA migrated data tables but forgot to rebuild seq