# Prevent model IDs from colliding after DB import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I’m importing data from a legacy system and I need to keep primary keys of a given table intact. For example, this record might exist in the legacy `countries` table:

```
id | alpha2 | name
––––––––––––––––––––
2  | SE     | Sweden
```

Importing this record with the ID is simple enough with:

```
Country.new(id: 2, alpha2: "SE", name: "Sweden").save!
```

Now that record exists in the system. If I create a new record without specifying the ID:

```
Country.new(alpha2: "NO", name: "Norway").save!
```

…Then Norway also exists in the system, and is assigned an ID of `1`.

The problem arises when I try to create another model like this:

```
Country.new(alpha2: "DK", name: "Denmark").save!
```

Because a record already exists with an ID of `2`, I have a collision and sure enough AR/PG throws an exception:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

Is there a way to work around this problem? Can I ask AR to look for the *next available* ID? Should I try updating the ID sequence after a DB import so any new records are given an ID at least one higher than the highest-number ID found in the legacy DB?

Comment: As you've suggested, you could start the ID count for new records at a point that is beyond your legacy IDs.  See `reset_pk_sequence` as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15108735/2622934).

Comment: Ah, that’s very helpful. Thanks. My question is pretty much the same as the one you linked to, so I’ll vote to close my question.